# Does my battery seriously have a problem or do I have a virus?

Tags: applications, battery, system-error

This notification keeps popping up on my phone and I don't know if it's real or not, it reads:

"Battery has been infected by 6 serious problem! Install DU Battery and all problems will be wiped out."

[image: Malware Notification]

Comment: Look, man. Look at the popup's horrible grammar. Now think: can a battery, which **is not programmable**, be *infected*? The obvious answer is no. Close that popup without tapping the **"Protect now"** and flee posthaste.

Comment: how do i get it to stop popping up??

Comment: You probably installed some weird app, and that's most likely the culprit. Unless you wish to start uninstalling them one by one, I recommend you to give us a list.

Comment: ilauncher, control center and inoty

Comment: Uninsatll the app which has any relations with DU battery. What i mean is the which is having option to install DU Battery in inside settings.

Comment: When pop up shows? Is it on any specific act or an app?

Answer (score 2):

**It's a virus/maleware.**

Sources that describe very similar situations:

http://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/658156-apus-du-battery-saver-virus.html

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/7XbiK-frhVA

It sounds like it's actually a really old scam (this may be a newer variant of it)  Here's a story from 2011 that sounds like the same issue:

http://www.pcworld.com/article/241967/sleazy_ads_on_android_devices_push_bogus_battery_upgrade_warnings.html

Answer (score 2):

To give a  view of why it is impossible for an app to diagnose much less than fix battery problems, a little background is in order

- Battery houses a sensor/chip that is responsible for  monitoring vital parameters like *temperature, voltage, NFC etc*. This information is conveyed to the OS  through one of the pins that makes contact when the battery is in place (normally three pins, one being for this and other two for charging / discharging)
- This information is conveyed to the battery driver portion of the ROM. These drivers cannot be modified permanently, even if your device is rooted, since these are initialised during boot up

Hence to identify state of the battery (other than the vital parameters) discussed above, you require a *physical* way of interacting with the battery. This should convince you that the claims made by the app are nonsense , aimed at attracting revenue

- Android doesn't need anti virus - see [Is an antivirus really needed for Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/341/131553). So that only leaves *malware* as the cause. Have a look at our [malware](/questions/tagged/malware)  tag for solutions to fix. [This](http://thedroidguy.com/2015/12/galaxy-s5-getting-pop-ups-about-virus-infection-1052833) suggests factory reset can fix, in which case you are lucky or you may need to flash stock ROM again- in any case make a back up of your data

Answer (score 0):

This is very annoying situation.

First thing to try is remove all cache files of those apps which has internet connectivity. On net there are many sites, those try to inject some malicious codes. This is first step to identify.

If first is not helpful, try to check the background running apps. Any suspicious app that you think, force stop that. See if it helps. If you find out any app which is on play store, you must contact and report this to developer.

You may also try to check all downloaded apps. May be something there.