# A virus on my phone which is not removing

Tags: factory-reset, motorola-droid-razr

I have Motorola Droid razr smart phone in which i got a virus called 'factory test' I have factory reset my phone and used antivirus for it but isn't removing from my phone what should be done to remove it completely?

[image: here is the screen shot of a virus]

Comment: That's a malware, I can confirm that definitely

Answer (score 0):

- Android devices are not susceptible to viruses as Windows machines are. To understand more see this [Is an antivirus really needed for Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/341/is-an-antivirus-really-needed-for-android). So, installing anti virus is not helping any, unless it scans for malware also
- From the screenshot those icons showing *factory reset* with Android icons appear to be *system* packages. Though I have no idea why there should be multiple copies.

There is no need to be concerned on this account IMO

Comment: This post is from 2010, since outdated. Now hackers are targeting smartphones, and Android seems to be the most important target due to multiple security flaws

Comment: @esQmo: while what you say is true on it's own,  the fact that Android is not vulnerable to virus is unchanged

Comment: we cannot argue here, but just try to search for monkey virus and several other posts by people claiming they phone were hit by malwares

Comment: There is no argument intended :). You are welcome to link sources which support your view and share for the benefit of all , including me. Please bear  in mind that the point was about *virus vulnerability* and not any other attack vectors. That has  not changed AFAIK , while on other aspects, Good guy Vs Bad Guy continues as ever

Comment: @esQmo: You may like to have a look at [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/160649/are-antiviruses-useful-if-you-only-download-well-known-applications#comment205559_160649) comment

Answer (score 0):

Android smartphones nowadays are very targeted by malwares - commonly from China.
There is no way to remove them by a simple reset, since they are installed as system apps.

You have two solutions. First simply flashing your phone which will remove all malwares.

Or, If you're skilled, you'll need to root your phone and install BusyBox then use adb shell to remove all those packages. Or you can use system apps removers on Google play to get rid of them.