# Do antivirus apps detect malware apps?

Tags: antivirus

As reported in the links below, there are malicious apps on Google Play.

Would android antivirus apps like Avast or AVG detect malicious apps that Google Play missed? Has it ever been document or have you experienced a situation where an anti-virus app detected a malware app?

PS Is there a database somewhere where all known malicious apps ever reported are documented so people can search to see if they have them on their phones?

- [Link 1](https://clark.com/technology/google-play-malware-app-hummingbad/)
- [Link2](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2018/01/menacing-android-botnet-still-thrives-16-months-after-coming-to-light/)

Comment: Google Play has started [play-protect](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2812853?hl=en-IN)  to do exactly this. Just switch it on and don't worry. And also don't install apps from unknown sources.

Comment: This wasn't always the case (Play-Protect), and thus made AV perhaps "required" or "recommended".

Answer (score 1):

- Android doesn't need anti virus (unlike Windows) but of course it is vulnerable to malware and Trojans. See [Is an antivirus really needed for Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/341/131553)
- So the so called anti virus apps have to block things like malware,adware etc, otherwise *there isn't any reason for them to be used*. If you see the Play Store  description of both apps you mentioned in your question, they **do block malware**. I haven't used them to confirm from first hand experience but the logic and Play Store description holds
- AFAIK there isn't a publicly available database of malicious apps and companies create / update and use their own databases. After all that's the only differentiator

Comment: Why state it does not need Anti-Virus, but then state it's vulnerable to Malware? This does not make sense. Also for further reading: https://www.cisecurity.org/advisory/multiple-vulnerabilities-in-google-android-os-could-allow-for-arbitrary-code-execution/

Comment: Also another list: https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-1224/product_id-19997/Google-Android.html

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow : 1. Android **is** vulnerable to Malware not for virus because the way virus propogates and works (not possible on Linux / Android). Hence the distinction. What you linked in both comments are **vulnerabilities** which are OS weaknesses or exploits which are a security threat. Malware may use the vulnerability to steal data or root methods could be based on some of those exploits but they do not equate to malware 2. List of vulnerabilities is known and published regularly with monthly patches upgrading the OS protection against them.//

Comment: //OP is asking for list of **malicious apps** for which there is no such list officially maintained AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

Most likely if google missed it the anti-virus software would miss it also.  It could be due to the programs heuristics that it does not get detected or because it is laying dormant waiting or it is disguised as a host application.  For the normal user who is using google play, I dont think that you even need to worry about getting a virus unless you are just simply downloading every ridiculous app you can find.  I don't use an antivirus on my phone and download all kinds of stuff that I am side-loading.  When and if you get a virus, you can usually detect abnormal activity with an ad-blocking app or vpn ad blocker because it is hitting your net connectivity. HTC Boost app will do this also. In the case when I have accidentally installed a virus by downloading stupid warez, malware bytes usually takes care of it when other programs fail to remove it completely.  simply download it, scan and uninstall until needed again.  Worse case scenario factory reset.